# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout inside FragmentScenario test

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing, androidx, android-fragmentscenario

I wrote a test using [FragmentScenario](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/testing/FragmentScenario):

```kotlin
@Test
fun test() {
    launchFragmentInContainer<MyFragment>(Bundle().apply { putParcelableArray(MY_DATA, getMyData()) })
    // checks here
}
```

However, I get following error:

```plaintext
Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
```

I only get the error when I launch my test (the app works). I tried to add `"com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"` to `androidTestImplementation` but it didn't help.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default theme for the activity that [FragmentScenario](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/testing/FragmentScenario) launches has a parent theme of `android:Theme.WithActionBar` - not the `MaterialComponents` theme that [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout) requires.

You should pass in the theme that you want to use.

For example, assuming your app has a theme declared as such:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

You'd use:

```kotlin
launchFragmentInContainer<MyFragment>(
    Bundle().apply { putParcelableArray(MY_DATA, getMyData()) },
    R.style.AppTheme
)
```